# How can I access the main component's functions from a page navigated to in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I've created an Ionic v2 application using the following command:

`ionic start my-app sidemenu --v2 --ts`.

Inside the `app.ts` file, I have some logic (functions) to do some things (like opening a modal and maintaining state for what the side menu should show). When a certain page (e.g. `pages/getting-started/getting-started.ts`) is shown, I'd like to reuse the same functions in `app.ts`. How do I access functions of `app.ts` from a page navigated to?

My `app.ts` looks like the following.

```
class MyApp {
 @ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav;
 private rootPage:any = GettingStartedPage;
 private pages:any;

 constructor(platform:Platform) {
  this.initializeApp();
  this.pages = { 
   'GettingStartedPage': GettingStartedPage, 
   'AnotherPage': AnotherPage //more pages and modals
  };
 }

 initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   StatusBar.styleDefault();
  });
 }

 openPage(page:string) {
  //when a user clicks on the left menu items, a new page is navigated to
  let component this.pages[page];
  this.nav.setRoot(component);
 }

 openModal(page:string) {
  //modals are opened here, there's more complicated logic
  //but this serves to demonstrate my problem
  let component = this.pages[page];
  Modal.create(component);
 }
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

My `getting-started.ts` looks like the following.

```
export class GettingStartedPage {
 constructor(
  platform:Platform, 
  viewController:ViewController,
  navController:NavController,
  navParams:NavParams) {
 }

 buttonClicked() {
  //i need to access app.ts openModal here
  //how do i call a method on app.ts?
  //like MyApp.openModal('SomeModal');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a shared service, you can communicate across the whole application.

Create a service class like

```
@Injectable() 
class SharedService {
  // use any kind of observable to actively notify about new messages
  someEvent:Subject = new Subject(); 
}
```

Provide it on your app

```
@App({
  ...
  providers: [SharedService]
})
```

Inject it to the `App` component and any component, directive, or service you want to communicate to the `App` component from

```
constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {}

someEventHandler() {
  this.sharedService.someEvent.next('some new value');
}
```

In the `App` component subscribe to notifications

```
constructor(sharedService:SharedService) {
  sharedService.someEvent.subscribe(event => {
    if(event == ...) {
      this.doSomething();
    }
  });
}
```

For details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 5):

With Ionic 2 you could use [Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/) for the communication between components.  For example, in your function `buttonClicked()` you could fire an event

```js
buttonClicked() {
  this.events.publish('functionCall:buttonClicked', thisPage);
}
```

and listen to it e.g. in the constructor of your main class to open the modal:

```
this.events.subscribe('functionCall:buttonClicked', userEventData => { 
  openModal(userEventData[0]);
});
```

You can even send data with the event (here: `thisPage`).

Answer (score 1):

in the page component TS file:

```
import { MyApp } from '../../app/app.component';

constructor(public AppComponent: MyApp) {
  }
```

then inside the page wherever you want to access that function:

```
this.AppComponent.functionName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can go for either

[Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/)

> Events is a publish-subscribe style event system for sending and
>   responding to application-level events across your app.

or [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html)

> EventEmitter is an angular2 abstraction and its only purpose is to
>   emit events in components.